# duplicate request from the client express nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i have a problem in my app that i cant resolve

first of all my app:

nodejs 0.8.14
express 3.1
passport-local 0.1

the problem is when i login in passport session the client request the page two times...

i discover that because i put a request var in the url

this in my router

```
exports.index=function(req,res)
{
    console.log('success: '+req.url);
    var sesion_usuario=validate(req.params.code_user);//if not valid return null
    if(sesion_usuario){
        res.render('logged',{title:'Hello'+sesion_usuario})
```

this in my browser

```
http://localhost:8000/YOGE7419
```

this in my app

```
app.get('/:code_user',routes.index);
```

and this is what im receiving in my prompt

```
success: /YOGE7419
success: /YOGE7419
DEBUG: validate error: maxlength not match
```

and the url transform in this

```
http://localhost:8000/YOGE7419#sthash.zp1bOY2d.dpbs
```

why is that??? whats happening between first and second request??
tnx

APP CONFIGURATION

```
app.configure(function()
{
    app.use(express.favicon(__dirname + '/public/images/favicon.png')); 
    app.set('port',  8000 || process.env.PORT);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.set('view options',{layout:false});
    //app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser({uploadDir:'./public/uploads/'}));
    app.use(express.cookieParser('nomatherwhatdoyoudobatman'));
    app.use(express.session());
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    //app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use(function(req, res, next){
        res.render('404.jade',
            {
                title: "404 - Page Not Found",
                showFullNav: false,
                status: 404,
                url: req.url
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: If you make request with browser, than second request may be init by brwoser for getting /favicon.ico

Comment: i commit favicon and still have a second request

Comment: Do you mean you get double requests when your browser visits the url? console.log('success', req.url) will show you which url is doing the request. If it's a request password makes then you can ignore this comment.

Comment: @Pickels req.url == /YOGE7419
prompt print 
success:  /YOGE7419
success:  /YOGE7419

Comment: do you think its a request password??

Comment: Could be, I am not familiar with password so I can't help you there.

Answer (score 2):

If express redirects the browser then the browser will send a repeated request (in my experience it was after 5 seconds) if the redirection has not completed.

By adding a timeout to the redirection's request I was able to avoid the duplicate request:

```
app.get('/path2', function( req, res ) {
    req.connection.setTimeout( 1000 * 60 * 10 ); // ten minutes
    console.log('path2');
});
```

For detailed discussion read here at GitHub [Link](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2512).

Answer (score 1):

The first request is automatically made by the browser, which requests favicon.ico, and of course, the second request is for the URL (Your URl).

Further More Refer

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/node-js-for-beginners/